# Show the relationship between the supremum and infimum of $f^2$ and $|f|$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Suppose $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $B$ satisfy $|f(x)| \le B$ for every $x\in [a,b]$.

Show that if $P = \{x_{0},...,x_{n}\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, then

$M(f^{2},[x_{i-1},x_{i}]) - m(f^{2},[x_{i-1},x_{i}]) \le
2B(M(f,[x_{i-1},x_{i}]) - m(f,[x_{i-1},x_{i}])) $

for every $1 \le i \le n$.

We are given a hint, namely that

$|f(x)^{2} - f(y)^{2}| = |f(x) - f(y)||f(x) + f(y)|$.

And this has something to do with Riemann integrals, or perhaps Darboux sums, as that is the section this homework was assigned in.

Comment: What are the functions $M$ and $m$?

Comment: Those are the supremum and infimum, respectively, of the function f (or f^2) over the set in the square brackets.

Comment: The result is obvious from the hint and triangle inequality $|f(x) +f(y) |\leq 2B$ and $|f(x) - f(y) |\leq M_f-m_f$